# Can wifi admins see exact user?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a wifi that uses Username + Password to log onto it. If a wifi admin decides to check the traffic going in and out of the router, can they see the exact user number? Or will it only show the device that the user is on? Any programs that can do that?

Comment: It depends on the system they're using, but yes, that is within the capability of most enterprise wireless systems.

Answer (score 1):

When using username + password authentication on Wi-Fi, there's usually a separate authentication server (usually a RADIUS server) that does the authentication. So if the Wi-Fi admin is also the RADIUS admin, then he can figure out who was authenticated to allow any given client to connect. If there is not a separate authentication server and the username/password database lives locally on the Wi-Fi infrastructure system, then the Wi-Fi admin can definitely know who's connected.

Comment: The outer username field ("anonymous identity") is visible to Wi-Fi APs without needing RADIUS admin access. Many enterprise APs, e.g. UniFi, automatically show it in the client list.